# Live Graph Matplotlib - using same window for updating graph in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

My program runs in a console, not a GUI application. the class has a render function that shows an OHLC using mpl_finance to show the internal representation of the system. my problem is that whenever i call the render function, it shows a window, and i have to close the window for the loop to continue. is there a way to make the loop continue and use the same window every time it calls the render function.

I have tried the FuncAnimation in matplotlib, yet it had two issues.
1 - the animation loop was separate than the main loop. so when the code get to the animation, it keep running forever without executing extra steps of the main loop.
2 - it shows the first chart only. maybe its matter of debugging.

Another solution is plt.ion(), but it throws ton of windows and all of them not responding.

The below is the code with the main issue, no animation and no plt.ion(). also i removed the data processing code to focus on the drawing part only

```
def render():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))

    candlestick_ohlc(ax1, ohlc, width=0.4, colorup='#77d879', colordown='#db3f3f')

    for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
        label.set_rotation(45)

    ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
    ax1.grid(True)

    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Price')
    plt.title("CandleStick Chart")
    plt.legend()
    plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.09, bottom=0.20, right=0.94, top=0.90, wspace=0.2, hspace=0)
    plt.show()
```

UPDATE 1:
so basically i have a main function, which has a for loop. the for loop calls two methods, one that update the internal state of a class (consider it like shifting the OHLC values) and the other calls the render functionality.
for that i defined the plt.ion before the for loop then inside the for loop called the function that update the inner state after that called the below before calling the render function

```
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))
```

then i passed the ax1 to the render function and called time.sleep(5)
The output is multiple windows and they show nothing, they're all empty. if i remove the plt.ion() the chart shows perfectly but i have to close it by hand to get the loop to continue and get a new chart window

Comment: when using plt.ion(), you should probably not create a new figure in every call to `render`.. it would be better to pass a handle to `ax1` as an argument to `render`

Comment: Thanks and please check the added update, as it still gives multiple windows

Comment: It is difficult to pinpoint the problem without an MWE. Instead of sleep you should probably call `plt.pause(5)`.. Are you accidentally calling `plt.figure()` inside render?

Comment: for the MWE, there is two data sources, so basically the code is quite pointless. for the plt.figure(), no, only before calling the render in the for loop i call those too `fig = plt.figure()`
        `ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1, 1), (0, 0))`

Comment: So you create the figure inside the loop? it should be done once outside.

Comment: perfect, i put figure outside the loop, used plt.ion and plt.pause and it worked like a charm, thanks alot